# Improve Speed of VBA - Application Volatile

Tags: vba, excel

I do not have much experience with VBA, and therefore need the help of this community for the following issue encountered:

I used application volatile in my code to run a series of calculation which slowed it down considerably. Without application volatile the code is fast enough for my purposes, but does not calculate/update row 8 (green row) when I change one of the input cells. Cell E8 (Image attached/ green row) references an estimate function which has several cases but will not update when any of cells in column E (or other columns) are changed without the use of Application Volatile.

So I am pretty sure whats causing it to slow down is application volatile, but I dont see away around this. Anyway I can go around using application volatile, or what step should I take to make it run faster. I've tried a bunch of things but to no avail. I am considering to remove the functions completely and add formulas to those Row 8 Cells (green).

```
Private Function EstimateFunctions(ByVal calc As String, Optional ByVal repdate As Date)

    'update1 As Range, update2 As Range

    Application.Volatile

    Dim rangeapproved As String
    Dim rangesum As String

    tempsum = 0

    Select Case calc

    Case "SumHrs"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_RESOURCE_HOURS"
            rangeapproved = "P" + CStr(n) + "_APPROVAL"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            If Range(rangeapproved).Value = "Y" Then
                temphrs = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))
            Else
                temphrs = 0
            End If

            If temphrs = "-" Then temphrs = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + temphrs

        Next n

        If finalsum = 0 Then finalsum = ""
        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumQty"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_EXPENSE_QTY"
            rangeapproved = "P" + CStr(n) + "_APPROVAL"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            If Range(rangeapproved).Value = "Y" Then
                tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))
            Else
                tempsum = 0
            End If

            If tempsum = "-" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        If finalsum = 0 Then finalsum = ""
        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumActuals"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_ACTUALS_SUMMARY"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For
            tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumDateActuals"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_ACTUALS_DATECOST"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For
            tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumPerformance"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_PERFORMANCE_SUMMARY"
            rangeapproved = "P" + CStr(n) + "_APPROVAL"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            If Range(rangeapproved).Value = "Y" Then
                tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))
            Else
                tempsum = 0
            End If

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumEarnedValue"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_EARNED_VALUE"
            rangeapproved = "P" + CStr(n) + "_APPROVAL"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            If Range(rangeapproved).Value = "Y" Then
                tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))
            Else
                tempsum = 0
            End If

            If tempsum = "-" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumPercentComplete"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_PERCENT_COMPLETE"
            rangeapproved = "P" + CStr(n) + "_BUDGET_SUMMARY"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            temp1 = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangeapproved), 0, 3).Value
            temp2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))

            If temp2 = "" Then temp2 = 0

            tempsum = temp1 * temp2

            'If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        If finalsum = 0 Then
            EstimateFunctions = ""
        Else
            EstimateFunctions = finalsum / WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("SUMMARY_BUDGET"), 0, 3)
        End If


    Case "SumActualExpense"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_ACTUAL_EXPENSES"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumExpenseForecast"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_ACTUALS_SUMMARY"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 4)

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum


    Case "SumCont"

        For n = 1 To 10 Step 1
            rangesum = "P" + CStr(n) + "_LABOUR_SUMMARY"

            If RangeExists(rangesum) = False Then Exit For

            tempsum = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 5)

            If tempsum = "" Then tempsum = 0
            finalsum = finalsum + tempsum

        Next n

        EstimateFunctions = finalsum

    End Select

End Function
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This question would be best answered on [codereview.se], given a title that *describes the purpose of the code* (as opposed to what you need to fix about it).

Comment: An idea to try out - add a nonsense variable to the method and give it a unique value in every call. That might give the wished effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was looking into an issue with a UDF recently, I found a page with (semi) helpful info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel). I just want to emphasis that:

> For correct calculation, all ranges that are used in the calculation should be passed to the function as arguments. If you do not pass the calculation ranges as arguments, instead of referring to the ranges within the VBA code of the function, Excel cannot account for them within the calculation engine.

In other words, Excel uses the parameters passed to the function to determine when recalculation is required.

You are correct in your belief that `Application.Volatile` is slowing things down. Using `Application.Volatile` tells Excel that it **always** need to recalculate this formula whenever **anything** changes.

And you are right that currently, how your code is formatted, the function requires `Application.Volatile` to stay updated. One potential way of eliminating `Application.Volatile` is to change your function to require the needed range(s) reference as a parameter. Something like the below:

```
Private Function EstimateFunctions(ByVal calc As String, ByVal rangesum as Range, Optional rangeapproved as Range, Optional ByVal repdate As Date)
```

---

Whenever you reference ranges within a UDF, but not as a parameter passed into the function, Excel is unable to correctly determine proper precedence for the calculation order, or which other ranges the UDF is dependent on.

As far as determining if it's possible to rework your code *so that passing all referenced ranges as parameters is a feasible solution* -- I would follow Mathieu Guindon's suggestion about going over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)....

Comment: This did make it a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.Volatile` isn't slowing down the code, it simply tells the worksheet to recalculate the function whenever *any* cell is changed in the worksheet. The code runs just as fast--`Application.Volatile` simply causes it to run much more frequently.

**Two ways I can think of to avoid Application.Volatile:**

1) Include all the ranges that may affect the function as input parameters. Then Excel will know when to recalculate based on the dependency tree. This may not be practical--it looks like you have 100-200 named ranges that your function may be referencing.

2) Use the worksheet object's `Worksheet_Change` event. Check whether the `Target` range is a range of interest (possibly by using `Application.Intersect`), and call a macro to update Row 8.

You should be able to speed up your code by directly referencing ranges instead of using `WorksheetFunction.Index`. For example, change

```
temphrs = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, Application.Caller.Column - (WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(rangesum), 0, 1).Column - 1))
```

to

```
temphrs = Range(rangesum).cells(1, Application.Caller.Column - Range(rangesum).Column + 1)
```